# Function call error with my class

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to prompt the user for two different employees and print their name, last name, ssn, payrate, and total pay for the week. Also it should determine if the worker worked any over time hours and recalculate their pay if they do.

I keep getting this error message:

```
No matching function call to Employee::Employee()
```

I will mark the lines which this message appears with a `// *****`.

The message appears 3 times. Please review my issues and help me fix them, and also explain what you did to fix them.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

/*
Name: Employee2
Author: --------
Date: 20/10/14 20:36
Description: A program that prints workers info using classes
*/
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    string firstname, lastname, ssn;
    int payRate, hours;

public:

    //A Four Parameter Constructor

    Employee (string newFirst, string newLast, string newSsn, int newpayRate, int newHours)
    {
        firstname = newFirst;
        lastname = newLast;
        ssn = newSsn;
        payRate = newpayRate;
        hours = newHours;
    }

    //Setter or Mutator Functions

    void setnewFirst(string newFirst)
    {
        firstname = newFirst;
    }

    void setnewLast(string newLast)
    {
        lastname = newLast;
    }

    void setnewSsn(string newSsn)
    {
        ssn = newSsn;
    }

    void setnewpayRate(int newpayRate)
    {
        payRate = newpayRate;
    }

    void setnewHours(int newHours)
    {
        hours = newHours;
    }

    void setEmployee(string newFirst, string newLast, string newSsn, int newpayRate, int     newHours)
    {
        firstname = newFirst;
        lastname = newLast;
        ssn = newSsn;
        payRate = newpayRate;
        hours = newHours;
    }

    //Accessor Functions

    string getfirstname ()
    {
        return firstname;
    }

    string getlastname ()
    {
        return lastname;
    }

    string getssn ()
    {
        return ssn;
    }

    int getpayRate ()
    {
        return payRate;
    }

    int gethours ()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    //Output Functions

    void printEmployee ()
    {
        cout << firstname << " " << lastname << endl << ssn << endl << payRate << endl <<   hours << endl;
    }

    //Functions to use employee info

    Employee newEmployee ()
    {
        Employee e1;      //**************
        string newFirst;
        string newLast;
        string newSsn;
        int newpayRate;
        int newHours;
        cout << "Enter First Name: " ;
        cin >> newFirst;
        cout << "Enter Last Name: " ;
        cin >> newLast;
        cout << "Enter SSN: " ;
        cin >> newSsn;
        cout << "Enter Payrate: " ;
        cin >> newpayRate;
        cout << "Enter Hours Worked: " ;
        cin >> newHours;
        e1.setnewFirst(newFirst);
        e1.setnewLast(newLast);
        e1.setnewSsn(newSsn);
        e1.setnewpayRate(newpayRate);
        e1.setnewHours(newHours);
        return e1;
    }

    //Function to Calculate Weekly Pay

    int calculatePay (int hours)
    {
        double result;
        if ( hours > 40 )
        {
            result = (hours - 40) * (payRate * 1.5) + (40 * payRate);
        }
        else
        {
            result = (hours * payRate);
        }
    }
};

Employee newEmployee();

//Main

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Employee firstEmployee;    // *********************
    Employee secondEmployee;   // *********************
    double result;
    firstEmployee = firstEmployee.newEmployee();
    secondEmployee = secondEmployee.newEmployee();
    cout << "First Employee Pay: " ;
    firstEmployee.printEmployee();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Secnod Employee Pay: " ;
    secondEmployee.printEmployee();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is intended to operate on the space in which the new object is being created. This means you don't need to complicate things by creating the additional object e1. Remove the problematic line:

```
Employee e1;      //**************
```

Remove all e1 references from your code; for example change

```
e1.setnewFirst(newFirst);
e1.setnewLast(newLast);
e1.setnewSsn(newSsn);
e1.setnewpayRate(newpayRate);
e1.setnewHours(newHours);
```

to:

```
setnewFirst(newFirst);
setnewLast(newLast);
setnewSsn(newSsn);
setnewpayRate(newpayRate);
setnewHours(newHours);
```

Constructors do not return values; remove:

```
    return e1;
```

Compile, test, debug, rinse, and repeat.